# Disable Shibboleth login on one URL route within Apache's mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shibboleth

I have a web application running on PHP Codeigniter framework, which uses rewrite rules to rewrite routes to front controller index.php. What I want to do is to exclude one route from shibboleth authentification.

Example:
We have 2 routes https://example.com/view/1457 and https://example.com/public/view/1457.
The first link should require user to login via Shibbo and the second one not. Both routes are rewritten to https://example.com/index.php?/view/1457 and https://example.com/index.php?/public/view/1457. I have one redirection rule in apache conf to redirect view/public/12345 to public/view/12345. Another non shibbo route is /assets which contains static files (css, js, ...)

My problem is that the public routes and redirect route to public (view/public/12345) are caught by shibbo login. But the assets route is not.

For me it looks like the request to https://example.com/public/view/1457 is rewritten to https://example.com/index.php?/public/view/1457 and this route is not whitelisted. But after logging I am redirected to this url https://example.com/public/view/1457

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

RewriteEngine On

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Apache vhost conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        #legacy redirection
        Redirect /view/public/12345 https://example.com/public/view/12345

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location /public>
                AuthType shibboleth
                ShibRequireSession Off
                require shibboleth
        </Location>

        <Location /assets>
                AuthType shibboleth
                ShibRequireSession Off
                require shibboleth
        </Location>

        <Location />
                AuthType shibboleth
                ShibRequireSession On
                ShibUseHeaders On
                require valid-user
                require shibboleth
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to be using

```
ShibRequestSetting requireSession false
```

instead of

```
ShibRequireSession Off
```

But that could just be a version thing - I'm not familiar with Shibboleth.

Also, it might be helpful to know what version of Apache you are using. The reason I ask is because you're using a combination of `Order/Allow/Deny` and `Require`. The latter is for Apache 2.4 and the former is for 2.2.

Past that, I'm afraid I don't know how else to help.